# How to open my own created vs code extension on the right side of vs code window

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I have created a vs code extension. My end result which I am expecting is a UI which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFapd.png).

But the issue is, VS code api's are not allowing me to create that. Instead i am only able to open a editor on the right side with my content inside.That looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7lo7.png)

This is my extension code

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

class CodeScoutViewProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

  resolveWebviewView(webviewView: vscode.WebviewView) {
    webviewView.webview.options = {
      enableScripts: true
    };

    webviewView.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
  }
}

function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand("extension.openCodeScout", () => {
      vscode.commands.executeCommand(
        "workbench.action.webview.openDeveloperTools"
      );
    }),
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(
      "code-scout",
      new CodeScoutViewProvider(context.extensionUri)
    ),
    vscode.commands.registerCommand("extension.openAnotherView", () => {
      const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
        "anotherView",
        "Another View",
        vscode.ViewColumn.Beside,
        {
          enableScripts: true
        }
      );

      panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
    })
  );
}

function deactivate() {}

function getWebviewContent() {
  return `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Code Scout View</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit/dist/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .actor>tspan{
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #container {
        display: flex;
        height: 90vh;
        margin: 15px;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        gap: 10px;
      }
      #inputContainer {
        display: flex;
        gap: 5px;
        height: 40px;
      }
      #textInput {
        width: 95%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(105, 105, 105, 0.5); /* dimgray with 50% opacity */
      }
      #sendButton {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #answer {
        flex-grow: 1;
        background-color: rgba(105, 105, 105, 0.5);
        border-radius: 10px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        border: solid;
        display: none;
        height: calc(100% - 40px); /* Adjust height based on input container */
        margin-top: 5px; /* Add a gap of 5px between header and answer div */
      }
      #loader {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vscode-light">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="inputContainer">
          <input type="text" id="textInput" name="textInput" />
            <i class="material-icons" id="sendButton" onclick="handleSubmit()">send</i>
        </div>
        <div id="answer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loader">
      <div class="MuiCircularProgress-root"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function handleSubmit() {
        console.log("Button Clicked");
      }
      document.getElementById('textInput').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          handleSubmit();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
    `;
}



module.exports = {
  activate,
  deactivate
};
```

This is my package.json configuration

```
{
  "name": "code-scout",
  "displayName": "Code-Scout",
  "description": "Chat bot for your own repository",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "publisher": "Code-Scout-IDE",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.82.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "extension.openCodeScout",
        "title": "Open Code Scout"
      },
      {
        "command": "extension.openAnotherView",
        "title": "Open Another View"
      }
    ],
    "keybindings": [
      {
        "command": "extension.openCodeScout",
        "key": "ctrl+l",
        "mac": "cmd+l"
      }
    ],
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "code-scout-view",
          "title": "Code-Scout",
          "icon": "media/timeline-solid.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "code-scout-view": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "code-scout",
          "name": "CODE-SCOUT",
          "icon": "media/timeline-solid.svg",
          "contextualTitle": "CODE-SCOUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "vscode-test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.6",
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.82.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.15.0",
    "@vscode/test-cli": "^0.0.4",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.3.8",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.7"
  }
}
```

In case if you are wondering where the first image is from, its called [Cursor](https://cursor.sh/)

The desired outcome I need is, onclick of shortcut key, or pressing ctrl+Shift+p and invoking a key word in VS code, i want to open a explorer box or a full rectangular box on the right with my content inside